# Responsiveness changes don't apply

Tags: html, css

How can I change the width of ".product-four" in the large screens @media to be like the one of ".product-one" in the same @media or to be 100% of its parent?
I have tried the :not() but it didn't work.

css:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.parent > div {
  background-color: rgb(177, 168, 168);
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

   /* Med Screens */
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .parent > div:not(.product-one) {
    width: calc((100% / 3) - 10px);
  }
  h3 {
    color: red;
  }
}

   /* Large Screens */
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .parent > div:not(.product-one, .product-four) {
    width: calc((100% / 2) - 10px);
  }
  h3 {
    color: rgb(22, 114, 22);
  }
}
```

thanks

Comment: Please create a complete demo of the code along with the HTML.

Comment: When I attached the html code, the question was not allowed to be posted.

Comment: What should I do؟

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example which should help you boil down your code to the essential problem. And I can't see anywhere that you set the width of product one.